# Embedding shell command in perl program

Tags: mysql, shell, perl

How can I embed a command like mysql -sN -e "query;"  inside a perl script so that my shell will be the one making the database connection. The query is a little complicated query which runs perfectly from the command line but when I set it up in my perl program, i get a bunch of errors like "string found where operator expected" , "bareword found where operator expected" and syntax error. Any idea how to do this without making giving perl access to the database?

Comment: You can't. You need to use [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.637/DBI.pm)

Comment: Can you post your Perl code?

Comment: Rather than exposing the vulnerabilities of both shell injection and SQL injection by invoking the `mysql` client with backticks, post relevant code in a question that seeks guidance on fixing that code so that you do not encounter "string found where operator expected" and "bareword found where operator expected" errors.  Perl's DBI module combined with DBD::mysql provides the better solution, including placeholders/bindvalues, and avoidance of hacky `mysql` cli calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use back quotes, the example below will place the output of the OS ls -l command into content.  Assuming you know the risks of what you are doing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $content=`ls -l`;
print $content;
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks guys.